# Scraping price from Countdown.co.nz using Beautiful soup and Python - not working likely needing pull request advice?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the price from countdown.co.nz which is a supermarket chain.
This product for example:
https://www.countdown.co.nz/shop/productdetails?stockcode=58643&name=countdown-fresh-tomatoes-cherry

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.countdown.co.nz/shop/productdetails?stockcode=58643&name=countdown-fresh-tomatoes-cherry'

# Send a request to the website and get its HTML content
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Referer': 'https://www.google.com/'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response)
html_content = response.content
print(html_content)
# Parse the HTML content using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

# Find the item name and price using their respective HTML elements
item_name = soup.find('div', {'class': 'product-detail-header'}).h1.text.strip()
price = soup.find('div', {'class': 'product-price'}).span.text.strip()

# Print the results
print(f"Item Name: {item_name}")
print(f"Price: {price}")
```

It hangs on the requests.get. Never ends and times out.
After reading this thread https://www.reddit.com/r/newzealand/comments/o5gwq1/web_scraping_supermarket_websites_for_product/

I've assumed it needs to use the pull method. But I can't figure out the next steps on how to convert my code to work. Any advice would be appreciated.

### **UPDATE-------------------------------------------------**

I've got the price, however I need to specify the store. As ideally I want a price for each of the stores listed here:

```
Store ID: 1431761, Store Name:  Countdown Blockhouse Bay
Store ID: 1225718, Store Name:  Countdown Northlands
Store ID: 3496448, Store Name: Countdown Alexandra
Store ID: 861615, Store Name: Countdown Amberley
Store ID: 2810973, Store Name: Countdown Andersons Bay
Store ID: 1050811, Store Name: Countdown Aotea
Store ID: 1155526, Store Name: Countdown Ashburton
Etc...
```

**I've managed to put this together:**

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.countdown.co.nz/api/v1/fulfilment/my/pickup-addresses'
url2 = 'https://www.countdown.co.nz/api/v1/products/58643'

# Step 1: Define the payload for the PUT request
payload = {
    "addressId": 1332617
}

# Step 2: Make the PUT request to update the address ID
print(payload)
put_response = requests.put(url, json=payload, headers={'X-Requested-With': 'OnlineShopping.WebApp', 'user-agent': 'some agent'})

# Step 3: Check the response from the PUT request
if put_response.status_code == 200:
    print("Address ID updated successfully!")
else:
    print("Failed to update the address ID.")

# Step 4: Proceed with the GET request
get_response = requests.get(url2, headers={'X-Requested-With': 'OnlineShopping.WebApp', 'user-agent': 'some agent'})
x2 = get_response.json()

# Step 5: Process the GET response as needed
print(x2)
```

However, the output doesnt seem to be changing the stores. The result is the same regardless what I put in address ID. Even if I make it bogus.
Obviously the put isn't following through to the get. How do I make this work? I'm so close I feel.

Comment: Are you able to visit that url from a regular browser on the same computer where you're running this code?

Comment: I can access the URL from my browser, `requests.get()` hangs, and receive a 403 status "Access Denied" when I try to access it with `curl`. I used the provided headers for `requests.get()` and `curl`. Looking at the network activity in Chrome developer tools shows a lot of dynamic content. You're probably not going to be able to access it with `requests`. You'll need something that handles JavaScript, like `selenium`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `stockcode` you could call the api, the product info is coming from directly:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.countdown.co.nz/api/v1/products/58643'
requests.get(url,headers={'X-Requested-With': 'OnlineShopping.WebApp','user-agent':'some agent'}).json()
```

Output is a JSON that holds a lot of information to the product, wich the browser uses to render:

```
{'sku': '58643', 'name': 'countdown fresh tomatoes cherry', 'brand': 'countdown fresh', 'genericName': 'tomatoes', 'variety': 'cherry', 'bigImageUrl': '9400597029001.jpg', 'smallImageUrl': '9400597029001.jpg', 'breadcrumb': {'department': {'key': 'Department', 'value': 1, 'isBooleanValue': False, 'name': 'Fruit & Veg', 'productCount': 0, 'group': None}, 'aisle': {'key': 'Aisle', 'value': 113, 'isBooleanValue': False, 'name': 'Fresh Salad & Herbs', 'productCount': 0, 'group': None}, 'shelf': {'key': 'Shelf', 'value': 225, 'isBooleanValue': False, 'name': 'Tomatoes', 'productCount': 0, 'group': None}, 'productGroup': None, 'dynamicGroup': None}, 'images': [{'big': 'https://assets.woolworths.com.au/images/2010/58643.jpg?impolicy=wowcdxwbjbx&w=900&h=900', 'small': 'https://assets.woolworths.com.au/images/2010/58643.jpg?impolicy=wowcdxwbjbx&w=500&h=500'}, {'big': 'https://assets.woolworths.com.au/images/2010/58643_1.jpg?impolicy=wowcdxwbjbx&w=900&h=900', 'small': 'https://assets.woolworths.com.au/images/2010/58643_1.jpg?impolicy=wowcdxwbjbx&w=500&h=500'}, {'big': 'https://assets.woolworths.com.au/images/2010/58643_2.jpg?impolicy=wowcdxwbjbx&w=900&h=900', 'small': 'https://assets.woolworths.com.au/images/2010/58643_2.jpg?impolicy=wowcdxwbjbx&w=500&h=500'}, {'big': 'https://assets.woolworths.com.au/images/2010/58643_3.jpg?impolicy=wowcdxwbjbx&w=900&h=900', 'small': 'https://assets.woolworths.com.au/images/2010/58643_3.jpg?impolicy=wowcdxwbjbx&w=500&h=500'}, {'big': 'https://assets.woolworths.com.au/images/2010/58643_4.jpg?impolicy=wowcdxwbjbx&w=900&h=900', 'small': 'https://assets.woolworths.com.au/images/2010/58643_4.jpg?impolicy=wowcdxwbjbx&w=500&h=500'}], 'unit': 'Each', 'quantity': {'min': 1.0, 'max': 100.0, 'increment': 1.0, 'value': 0.0, 'quantityInOrder': None, 'purchasingQuantityString': None}, 'productStoresStockLevel': None, 'price': {'originalPrice': 6.49, 'salePrice': 5.9, 'savePrice': 0.59, 'hasBonusPoints': False, 'isClubPrice': False, 'isSpecial': True, 'isNew': False, 'canShowOriginalPrice': True, 'discount': None, 'total': None, 'isTargetedOffer': False, 'averagePricePerSingleUnit': None, 'purchasingUnitPrice': None, 'orderedPrice': None, 'isUsingOrderedPrice': False, 'currentPricingMatchesOrderedPricing': None}, 'size': {'cupPrice': 0.0, 'cupMeasure': None, 'packageType': 'punnet', 'volumeSize': '250g'}, 'alcohol': None, 'healthStarRating': 0, 'origins': ['Product of New Zealand'], 'description': None, 'shopperNotes': '', 'allergens': None, 'claims': None, 'endorsements': None, 'ingredients': None, 'nutrition': None, 'warnings': None, 'contents': None, 'productDisclaimerMessage': 'Information provided on this page is supplied to assist our customers to select suitable products. However, products and their ingredients are liable to change at short notice, which may affect nutritional, country of origin, ingredient and allergen information. Therefore, you should always check product labels before consuming. If you require specific information to assist in your purchasing decision, we recommend that you make further enquiries of the manufacturer (see contact details on the packaging) or contact us on 0800 404040.', 'nutritionVerificationMessage': None, 'productTags': [{'tagType': 'IsSpecial', 'multiBuy': None, 'bonusPoints': None, 'additionalTag': None, 'targetedOffer': None}], 'averageWeightPerUnit': 0.0, 'supportsBothEachAndKgPricing': False, 'selectedPurchasingUnit': None, 'availabilityStatus': None, 'isSuccessful': True, 'rootUrl': 'http://shop.countdown.co.nz', 'context': {'shopper': {'firstName': None, 'isShopper': False, 'isLoggedIn': False, 'hasOnecard': False, 'oneCardBalance': None, 'shopperIdHash': None, 'shopperScvId': '', 'sessionGroups': None, 'orderCount': None, 'isSupplyLimitOverrideShopper': False, 'isPriorityShopper': False, 'isChangingOrder': False, 'changingOrderId': None, 'hasActiveDeliverySubscription': False}, 'fulfilment': {'address': 'Glenfield', 'selectedDate': None, 'selectedDateWithTZInfo': None, 'startTime': None, 'endTime': None, 'method': 'Courier', 'cutOffTime': None, 'isSlotToday': False, 'isAddressInDeliveryZone': True, 'isDefaultDeliveryAddress': False, 'areaId': 77, 'suburbId': 0, 'pickupAddressId': 0, 'fulfilmentStoreId': 9443, 'perishableCode': 'P', 'locker': None, 'expressFulfilment': {'isExpressSlot': False, 'isLastExpressHourWindow': False}}, 'enabledFeatures': ['HaveYouForgotten', 'ProjectShore', 'ManagedServiceBar', 'RecipesAddToTrolley', 'SavedRecipes', 'ProductStraps', 'DeliverySubscriptionSignUp', 'FirstTimeShopper', 'OrderConfirmation', 'NewDeliverySubscriptionPage', 'CancelOrder', 'CountryOfOriginInAccordion', 'PiesEnableEachUnitForKgProducts', 'ForgotPassword', 'JQueryDeprecationLogging', 'PaperPackingSlipPreference', 'EnableDeliverySaverRetryPayment', 'RecipesInApp', 'DeliverySaverBannerOnTrolleyPage', 'OnesiteIA', 'RecipeCategorySeo', 'EnableBoostsLandingPage', 'CustomerSelfService', 'MerchantHostedLocalStorefront', 'ChangeOrder', 'ChangeOrderChangedPriceModal', 'ChangeOrderIndicateChangedPriceInProductList', 'ChangeOrderPromptHomepage', 'AccountMenuMyOrdersLink', 'HideTargetedCategoryOffersBanner', 'TargetedCategoryOffers', 'LazyLoadProductStampImages', 'OptimizelyWeb', 'ChangeOrderAccountMenu'], 'shoppingListItems': [], 'basketTotals': None, 'advancedSettingsResponse': None}, 'messages': None}
```

And also the prices:

```
requests.get(url,headers={'X-Requested-With': 'OnlineShopping.WebApp','user-agent':'some agent'}).json()['price']
->
{'originalPrice': 6.49, 'salePrice': 5.9, 'savePrice': 0.59, 'hasBonusPoints': False,...}
```

Comment: Thanks man - I'll investigate this next few days.
I also need to figure out how to do this by store - as there should be a store code and stock code.

Comment: Hey - this is perfect. Notice in top right of screen it asks where your store is? Is there a way of also parsing the product and store code? Unsure how to find store code or how that works.

Also - if you don't mind, how did you figure this out?

Comment: If you look into the subsequent requests when accessing via your browser after you change location two cookies get set `_abck` and `akavpau_vpwww`.
When I copied the whole request in the network tab as "curl (cmd)" and pasted into postman as that includes all the cookies then I can see the request does return the correct locations details.
As I am also interested in this.